# MaxDop setting for OLTP with 8 processors

Tags: sql-server-2008, parallel-processing

I need to set MAXDOP for SQL 2008 R2 server for OLTP.  It got 8 processors.
What is the recommended setting.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the only answer is "it depends", depends on the workload, size of the tables involved, number of concurrent transactions, and acceptable performance. I would benchmark the default, 8, 6 and 4, assuming you really have 8 physical processors, not cores and/or hyperthreading.  There's a few guidelines [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/329204)